# Convolutional Neural Network - how to check its performance or how to see if it is beneficial regarding a specific problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to predict license plate text using Convolutional neural networks. It is the so called segmentation-free approach, where segmentation of a license plate is not necessary after the detection of the plate and we can already apply the character recognition (look e.g. here: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8078501 & https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3009977.3010052). In both articles the authors use Convolutional Neural networks, where the networks are split into branches after some convolutional layers.
I also created a similar model with 7 branches because I only have license plates with 7 characters (35 possibilities for each position on a license plate).

This is the model:

```
def create_model(input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    model = efnB0_model (input_img)
    model = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(model)
    model = Dropout(0.2)(model)
    backbone = model

    branches = []
    for i in range(7):
       branches.append(backbone)
       branches[i] = Dense(360, name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_16000")(branches[i])
       branches[i] = BatchNormalization()(branches[i])
       branches[i] = Activation("relu") (branches[i])
       branches[i] = Dropout(0.2)(branches[i])
          
       branches[i] = Dense(35, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_output")(branches[i])

   output = Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
   output = Reshape((7, 35))(output)
   model = Model(input_img, output)

   return model
```

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
The model summary:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_11 (InputLayer)           (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
efficientnet-b0 (Model)         (None, 7, 7, 1280)   4049564     input_11[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
avg_pool (GlobalAveragePooling2 (None, 1280)         0           efficientnet-b0[9][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)            (None, 1280)         0           avg_pool[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_0_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 360)          461160      dropout_15[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_1_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 360)          461160      dropout_15[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_2_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 360)          461160      dropout_15[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_3_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 360)          461160      dropout_15[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_4_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 360)          461160      dropout_15[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_5_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 360)          461160      dropout_15[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_6_Dense_16000 (Dense)    (None, 360)          461160      dropout_15[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNor (None, 360)          1440        branch_0_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (BatchNor (None, 360)          1440        branch_1_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNo (None, 360)          1440        branch_2_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNo (None, 360)          1440        branch_3_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNo (None, 360)          1440        branch_4_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (BatchNo (None, 360)          1440        branch_5_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (BatchNo (None, 360)          1440        branch_6_Dense_16000[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)       (None, 360)          0           batch_normalization_8[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)       (None, 360)          0           batch_normalization_9[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)       (None, 360)          0           batch_normalization_10[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)      (None, 360)          0           batch_normalization_11[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_11 (Activation)      (None, 360)          0           batch_normalization_12[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_12 (Activation)      (None, 360)          0           batch_normalization_13[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)      (None, 360)          0           batch_normalization_14[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_16 (Dropout)            (None, 360)          0           activation_7[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_17 (Dropout)            (None, 360)          0           activation_8[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)            (None, 360)          0           activation_9[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)            (None, 360)          0           activation_10[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_20 (Dropout)            (None, 360)          0           activation_11[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_21 (Dropout)            (None, 360)          0           activation_12[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_22 (Dropout)            (None, 360)          0           activation_13[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_0_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           12635       dropout_16[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_1_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           12635       dropout_17[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_2_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           12635       dropout_18[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_3_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           12635       dropout_19[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_4_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           12635       dropout_20[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_5_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           12635       dropout_21[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
branch_6_output (Dense)         (None, 35)           12635       dropout_22[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 245)          0           branch_0_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_1_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_2_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_3_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_4_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_5_output[0][0]            
                                                                 branch_6_output[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)             (None, 7, 35)        0           concatenate_1[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 7,376,209
Trainable params: 3,321,605
Non-trainable params: 4,054,604
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I am now wondering how I can check if this model is able to predict the license plate text correctly besides the accuracy measure? When I look to the accuracy measure I get huge overfitting towards the training data (acc: 0.4x) and very poor performance regarding the validation data (about 0.18 accuracy), when I use ImageNet weights via Transfer Learning. What would you do in my case? I already tried to use the network without Transfer Learning, but with data augmentation or a simpler architecture but then I get poor results in general. Does this mean that the architecture is not beneficial for my problem?

Edit: I updated the model: It is now a lot smaller but I still have this overfitting problems...

Answer (score 1):

You have a really huge model for this task.
For starters you could try adding much lighter denses. You could try directly with:

```
branches = []
for i in range (7):
            branches.append (backbone)
            branches[i] = Dense (35, activation="softmax", name="branch _" + str (i) + "_ output") (branches[i])
```

Of course you have overfitting, you can try adding dropout.
Although I think the model is too big and you could probably have the numbers / characters misaligned.

There are three concepts that could help you in this task:

- Detect the LP previously.
- STN: Spatial Transform Network, apply a geometric transformation to the input or a specific zone of features. This allows you if there is only one object try to align the network before predicting the numbers. You can use this: https://github.com/oarriaga/STN.keras
- CTC: Connectionist Temporal Classification, this is normally more suitable when the amount of text is variable but it is another way to align.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting answer! To reduce overfitting I added Dropout.It did not get much better. What is meant by "you could probably have the numbers / characters misaligned"? Detecting the license plate is not necessary I thought because the pictures capture only the license plate. I have never heard about STN and CTC but I will take a look to these concepts.